# How access validation error messages before sending view?

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel when validation fails, the request is redirected to the view with validation `$errros`. I need to access this message in controller. What is the correct method to access them? I user `Request` class in validation so I cannot use:

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);
$messages = $validator->messages();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've used `withErrors` when redirecting, you can get the error message bag yourself directly from the session:

```php
$errors = session('errors');
```

Once you have the error message bag, you can get the messages with `$errors->getMessages()` or, to get a flat array, `$errors->all()`.

Comment: Thanks, using that, I can reach errors array by `session('errors')->getBags()['default']->toArray()`. I guess there should be better way. Isn't it?

Comment: @PHPst - If you want a flat array: `session('errors')->all()`. If you want the messages in their original format: `session('errors')->getMessages()`

Answer (score 0):

The validator's messages are available as `$validator->messages()`.

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);
$messages = $validator->messages();
```

Comment: I think @JosephSilber's answer is the closest you'll get, then.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna send back the messages to be viewed on the page, then send it back with the redirect:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    Session::put('failure_message', 'Failure!');
    return Redirect::to('whateverpage')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::all());
```

if you wanna see what message was generated, first create some messages to key off of:

```
$messages = array(
    'same'    => 'Your passwords don\'t match.',
    'required' => 'The field ":attribute" is required',
    'alpha'   => 'The field ":attribute" can only contain letters',
    'min'     => 'The field ":attribute" must be ":min" characters or greater.',
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
$messages = $validator->messages();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can access the error message within the controller.

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);
$validator->errors()->get('date');
```